# Extracting corresponding values in JSR223 post processor in JMeter Randomly

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Hi All / Dimitri T Could you please post your valuable thoughts on  extracting corresponding Values (For example ItemID1 and ItemSlot1) in one block of code ***randomly***. I was able to write below Jsr223 postprocessor code and it is working fine. But when there are Blank spaces in ItemSlot id, then they are not fetching. From below code , i am passing ${rannum} under "Match No" in required regular expression.

Note: There will be more than 100 corresponding values. In some cases, we won't have ItemSlot1.i.e Blank/null values are appearing from server response. Hence, my script is not picking corresponding values.

### Application Server Response:

"viewSaleListingLink": "https://Example.com/cars/item/search/-/listing/ItemID1/100011142",
"saleCountry": "",
"saleNote": "",
"bidLiveUrl": "https://Example.com/cars//registration?p_p_id=RegistrationPortlet_WAR_PWRWeb&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&ItemSlot1=103009468",

### JSR223PostProcessor Code

import java.math.MathContext;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

// Read occurance values from pervious response
def Max = Integer.parseInt( vars.get("ItemID1_matchNr"));

int min=1;

int rannum =  min + (int) (Math.random() * ((Max - min) + 1));

log.info("Values id ="+rannum);

vars.put("rannum",rannum.toString());

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FnTF.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to extract a random match/pair of matches from the response using Regular Expression Extractor - it's sufficient just to provide `0` as the "Match No" and it will automatically fetch the random match group so you won't have to write any code:

[image]

Also be aware that [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) are executed in the order they appear (upside down) so:

- If your JSR223 PostProcessor is above the Regular Expression Extractor - `ItemID1_matchNr` will be undefined
- If your JSR223 PostProcessor is below the Regular Expression Extractor - your `rannum` variable won't have any value

Also your response seems to be [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) so it makes sense switching to [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/) which is more powerful and convenient